# Debian Jessie grub reinstall

Tags: debian, grub2, debian-jessie

I had a Debian Jessie installation on my laptop. I tried to boot live from USB a Kali linux distro and I lost grub.

I have a very important project on this drive. I tried to reinstall grub but failed. Can anyone tell me a way to either reinstall grub correctly or just get the two files from the disk and then format it?

My (non-root) user is password protected, will this cause any problems? Of course I remember the password

Answer (score 0):

In order to repair grub you need to boot via live-USB distro like Ubuntu, debian or another one.
There is the solution how to repair grub on Debian system https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/reinstalling-grub-on-unbootable-debian/.

Also, pay attention whether your system was installed in uefi or bios mode. There are some differences in restoring.